# Help routing traffic trough VirtualBox

Tags: dnsmasq, virtualbox-networking

I’m trying to build a Hotspot with a WIN 10 laptop, a Cisco Meraki MR-18 Access Point (AP), an Oracle VirtualBox 5.1.4, and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, running as a Virtual Machine (VM), to service the incoming wireless connections. The laptop has a physical Ethernet port connected to the MR-18 AP and a wireless connection to the Internet.

[image: Setup]

The Problem: From an smart device, I can establish a wireless connection through the MR-18 AP, open a SSH session, connect to an HTTP server on the Ubuntu VM, or PING (thus resolve) any domain name. However, the MR-18 AP keeps reporting having ‘No Internet’ and if I try to open any URL on the IPAD’s browser, this will not work.

VirtualBox creates the first net adapter and assigns IP address: 10.0.2.15/24 and Default Route: 10.0.2.2/24 to Ubuntu’s interface enps03. This is the connection to the Windows 10 Host OS.

The 2nd VirtualBox net adapter is defined to establish a bridge between the laptop’s physical Ethernet port and the 2nd Ubuntu’s enps08 virtual Ethernet interface. This is the connection to the MR-18 AP.

[image]

After creating these two network connections on Ubuntu, none of the two virtual Ethernet interfaces appears on the /etc/network/interfaces file; however, the first interface enp0s3 is UP and running and communicating with the host OS as per ifconfig.  The second virtual interface enp0s8 will go UP and running once it is declared on the interfaces file.

Interfaces file

```
Interfaces file
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet dhcp

auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet static
    address 192.168.2.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Ifconfig

```
  enp0s3   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:0b:75:e8  
      inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe0b:75e8/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:38693 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:17734 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:34637394 (34.6 MB)  TX bytes:2140816 (2.1 MB)

enp0s8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:b4:74:9d  
      inet addr:192.168.2.1  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:feb4:749d/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:39564 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:10545 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:3753385 (3.7 MB)  TX bytes:1238937 (1.2 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:1670 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1670 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:216048 (216.0 KB)  TX bytes:216048 (216.0 KB)
```

Ubuntu’s dnsmasq is configured to service DHCP and DNS requests on 2nd interface enp0s8, therefore it will assign an IP address and a default route to the MR-18 AP.

dnsmaq.conf

```
domain-needed
bogus-prtv
filterwin2k
local=/oeinc.lan/
server=192.168.1.1
interface=enp0s8
bind-interfaces
expand-hosts
domain=oeinc.lan
dhcp-range=192.168.2.50,192.168.2.150,72hs
```

dnsmasq

```
— dnsmasq.service - dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/dnsmasq.service.d
           â””â”€50-dnsmasq-$named.conf, 50-insserv.conf-$named.conf
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2016-08-23 15:09:09 EDT; 3 days ago
 Main PID: 1748 (dnsmasq)
   CGroup: /system.slice/dnsmasq.service
       â””â”€1748 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq -x /var/run/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.pid -u   dnsmasq -r /var/run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf -7 /etc/dnsmasq.d,.dpkg-dist,.dpkg-old,.dpkg-new --local-service --trust-  anchor=.,19036,8,2,49AAC11D7B6F6446702E54A1607371607A1A41855200FD2CE1CDDE32F24E8FB5

Aug 24 05:30:46 oehotspot dnsmasq-dhcp[1748]: DHCPREQUEST(enp0s8)  192.168.2.100 00:18:0a:84:0b:03
Aug 24 05:30:46 oehotspot dnsmasq-dhcp[1748]: DHCPACK(enp0s8) 192.168.2.100 00:18:0a:84:0b:03 m00180a840b03
Aug 24 11:14:16 oehotspot dnsmasq-dhcp[1748]: DHCPDISCOVER(enp0s8) 00:18:0a:84:0b:03
Aug 24 11:14:16 oehotspot dnsmasq-dhcp[1748]: DHCPOFFER(enp0s8) 192.168.2.100 00:18:0a:84:0b:03
Aug 24 11:14:16 oehotspot dnsmasq-dhcp[1748]: DHCPREQUEST(enp0s8) 192.168.2.100 00:18:0a:84:0b:03
Aug 24 11:14:16 oehotspot dnsmasq-dhcp[1748]: DHCPACK(enp0s8) 192.168.2.100 00:18:0a:84:0b:03 m00180a840b03
Aug 24 11:14:20 oehotspot dnsmasq-dhcp[1748]: DHCPDISCOVER(enp0s8) 28:d2:44:b3:96:a5
Aug 24 11:14:20 oehotspot dnsmasq-dhcp[1748]: DHCPOFFER(enp0s8) 192.168.2.128 28:d2:44:b3:96:a5
Aug 24 11:14:20 oehotspot dnsmasq-dhcp[1748]: DHCPREQUEST(enp0s8) 192.168.2.128 28:d2:44:b3:96:a5
Aug 24 11:14:20 oehotspot dnsmasq-dhcp[1748]: DHCPACK(enp0s8) 192.168.2.128 28:d2:44:b3:96:a5 Carlitros
```

The network Interfaces on the Windows 10 laptop:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Carlitros
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : Yes
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : oeinc.lan
```

Ethernet adapter Ethernet: (this is the Bridge to Ubuntu virtual Ethernet interface)

```
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : oeinc.lan
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I218-V
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 28-D2-44-B3-96-A5
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::404a:2b1e:3ab2:fe62%7(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.128(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : August 24, 2016 1:49:06 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : August 27, 2016 11:53:29 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 120115780
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1E-2D-F0-7F-28-D2-44-B3-96-A5
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

```
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 0A-00-27-00-00-06
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::8dcf:5844:a517:227f%6(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 386531367
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1E-2D-F0-7F-28-D2-44-B3-96-A5
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

```
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-N 7260
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : E8-B1-FC-28-4F-29
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::54f7:c605:ff1a:a7f8%2(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.5(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : August 24, 2016 1:33:08 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : August 25, 2016 11:53:21 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 48804348
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1E-2D-F0-7F-28-D2-44-B3-96-A5
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Comment: please format to make it more readable.

Comment: @Terrance, Thanks for reformatting!.  I didn't know how to do it.  Also, I wanted to include several images but since this was my first posting, it was not possible.

Comment: You're welcome!  I just added your images so they can be clicked on or seen right from your question.  =)

Comment: I think I see your problem.  I might be wrong, but in your network picture I do not see anything with 192.168.1.1 as an IP in the VM, so in your dnsmasq.conf file you might want to change `server=` to `server=192.168.2.1`.  Just from observing.

Comment: Terrance, thank you very much for your comments.  IP 192.168.1.1. is assigned to the Wi-Fi router serving the Win10 laptop. It provides DHCP and DNS service. Also, I can ping a valid domain name or hostname by name, such as google.com,  from a wireless client to the MR-18 AP.  For this to happen, the domain must be resolved by an external DNS. This is what it is confusing, DNS seems to be working fine for pinging. I'll try your suggestion.